# Azure DevOps- Publish task build failed

Tags: excel, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, wildcard

I have a publish task in Azure Devops pipeline which should publish an excel file with extension .xlsx .
am using this below command but its not working. can someone help me with the wildcards?
this excel file is dynamic and date,month parameters keeps on changing.

```
format: SonarQube Issue Extract_2020-08-04.xlsx

task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'C:\Users\320066547\agent\_work\3\s\SonarFetchIssues\target\*.xlsx'
    ArtifactName: 'IssuesOutput'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: can you post the YAML file

Comment: Could you also post the associated error/log please ?

Comment: ##[error]Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: C:\Users\320066547\agent\_work\3\s\SonarFetchIssues\target\*.xlsx

Comment: I have posted the YAML publish task above

Comment: What about making sure the excel is in a dedicated sub(directory) and then publish the entire directory, instead of using a filename?

Comment: Yes, that was working..But I wanted a second approach on publishing the content without using any folder

Answer (score 0):

If using a YAML pipeline look at using the [PublishPipelineArtifact task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops)

```
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
    inputs:
       artifact: drop
       targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

This will publish all the artifacts in the pipeline. From there can narrow down the exact path that is being published.

Alternatively too can do run a Powershell task before your publish to see exactly what your folder structure looks like on the agent:

```
-powershell: Get-ChildItem -Path 'Insert root path' -recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly stated in the task:

> Path to publish: The folder or file path to publish. This can be a
> fully-qualified path or a path relative to the root of the repository.
> **Wildcards are not supported**. Variables are supported. Example: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

[image]